# define in sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I set this in a .h file:

```
#define ID_ACTIVE 2
```

then used this in a .m file sqlite statement:

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT task FROM tasks WHERE task_state = 'ID_ACTIVE'";
```

but when I look at 'query' via gdb it gives me this query statement:

```
SELECT task FROM tasks WHERE task_state = 'ID_ACTIVE'
```

Shouldn't the preprocessor have replaced ID_ACTIVE with 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you can use the **ID_ACTIVE** as an int variable.

1. If **task_state** is a string, use,

   ```
   NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT task FROM tasks WHERE task_state = '%d'", ID_ACTIVE];
   ```
2. If it is a number, then use,

   ```
   NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT task FROM tasks WHERE task_state = %d", ID_ACTIVE];
   ```

Comment: No. Actually *ID_ACTIVE* is defined as 2(*integer*), so we have to use integer format. If it is defined as @"2"(*string*), then we should use *%@*.